# If MSSQL machine is maxed out on resources, can it drop off the network and become un-pingable?

Tags: networking, ping, sql-server, ms-sql

The issue is that our SQL machine will just disappear from the network with `request timed out` when I attempt to ping it.

I have to deal with an "IT Guy" who is telling me that it is because Microsoft SQL 2012 running on Server 2012 R2 is too "busy" and that's why it's unreachable.

The pings have a reply time of <5ms then `unreachable` several times then <5ms.  If the machine were busy, I'd expect it to have long ping reply times...not just unreachable and then great pings.

Also, the machine is 16 core with 64GB of memory.

[image: Ping screenshot]

Comment: Is it on the same local network?

Comment: Don't beleive that  IT guy...

Comment: Same local network.  They're both VMs.  The guy denies everything is an issue, but I don't have enough access to the machines or visibility to prove him wrong most of the time.  Is there any "hard evidence" that I can present that would prove him wrong?

Comment: If they are VM's can you verify that "IT guy" has not limited the amount of CPU or memory to an insufficient amount.

Comment: have you tried pinging it from a different device? I know our SQL server goes a bit silly when it maxes out on RAM.

Comment: Long ping reply times wouldn't be because the machine was busy as that does not affect ping. A machine is much more likely to ignore or drop packets if it has no resources to deal with them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can destroy MSSQL, the Windows OS, and Disk system; and the machine should never become unreachable.  Slow as heck, but never a dropped ICMP packet.  At least in my 20 years of demolishing MSSQL (usually by a really bad report)